# duda ::after y ::before

Tags: css

Soy relativamente nuevo en css, y estoy ahora intentando entender los conceptos de las pseudoclases after y before. Todo esto lo estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta a través de internet, así que no tengo un referente claro a quién preguntar, de forma que lo haré por aquí; Según he entendido, ¿las pseudoclases after y before son meramente estéticas y la única razón de su uso es la comodidad, para colocarse fácilmente alrededor del elemento padre y no pegarse la paliza de crear nuevos elementos padre para complementar al primero?

Comment: Si, basicamente es puramente decorativo, como todo en css. Es una herramienta que te da css para crear "elementos" sin tocar el html con fines decorativos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En resumen, si, es de uso estético/decorativo para elementos en el DOM